# How to deploy a Powershell module in company?

Tags: powershell

I have my own Powershell module which I use on many servers. I keep it on a network share which is added on some machines to the `PSModulePath` variable: `\\\Server\Scripts\MyModule\`.

This allowed me to always use the latest version of my module on each server and I only had to update a single copy.

Now with Powershell 5 there is an issue. If I have this network path in PSModulePath I can't remote onto this machine.

```
Enter-PSSession : The term 'Measure-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operab
le program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession Server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Measure-Object:String) [Enter-PSSession], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It's a known error and it could be fixed with enabling second hoop.

Is there a better way to deploy a module and keep it always up-to-date then my approach?

Comment: You can use _Group Policy_ or some kind of a _Configuration Management_ system(DSC, Chef, anything else..) to push the modules onto your boxes.

Comment: You might set up an [internal PowershellGet repository](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/05/20/setting-up-an-internal-powershellget-repository/)...

Comment: Can you just run `Import-Module \\Server\Scripts\MyModule`?

And just to better understand. You updated `PSModulePath` on Server2 (for example) which has WMF5 and now you cannot remote into Server2? And  if you remove your path from `PSModulePath` variable, you can?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you have an UNC path and second hoop not configured than you can't remote to that computer.